# Permissões Laravel 5 utilizando Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou utilizando o laravel 5 com uma box Homestead utilizando vagrant e virtualbox para isso, assim como demonstrado na documentação do framework: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup o problema que estou tendo é em relação as permissões de escrita nos arquivos, estou editando os arquivos e não estou tendo sucesso em salvar, aparece o erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Permission denied
```

executei os comandos a partir de minha Homestead: `sudo chmod 777 -R <projeto>` mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você precisa setar apenas a pasta *storage*. Dentro do seu projeto:

```
chmod 744 storage
```

ps: está seguro que você está realmente usando o caminho da Homeastead? Esse caminho parece diferente.

Comment: A pasta storage e a pasta bootstrap.